# command "python setup.py egg info" failed with error code 1 in ~~

Tags: python, django, mysql-python, centos6

```
[root@myserver bin]# pip3.5 install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ahudhqst/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in     <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ahudhqst/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in     <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ahudhqst/MySQL-python/
[root@myserver bin]#
```

I failed to install MySQL-python (for django). Can I know why this error occur? I'm using centos 6.5

Comment: As the error states, you have to install the `ConfigParser` module first

Comment: Isn't `ConfigParser` in the standard library? What do you get if you do `python -c 'import ConfigParser'` in the command line?

Comment: when I do `python -c 'import ConfigParser'` in the command line, it just do nothing (it might means successfully import ConfigParser). There are no errors exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall python and download and install it again. There are three kinds of downloads web-based installer, executable installer, embeddable zip file. You have to make sure you download the executable installer. When you are done. Go to command prompt(Make sure you have administrative privilege) and type python. It should return you back the python version. type pip and it should return you back the commands that pip can execute. That way you make sure that it is installed properly. If it is not you need to get-pip. Otherwise you would need to update setuptools especially for an older version of python This page has all the necessary command line prompts https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/